# Failing to create distribution app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to upload my app into App Store through Xcode, I read a few sites and set the code signing to "iOS Distribution" but when I tried to Archive, an error appear "No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found."

I've created a new distribution Provisioning Profile in developer.apple.com and link it to my app and selected the distribution certificate to it. I then downloaded this profile and manage to select it in the provisioning profile section in xCode->build settings->code signing. But now I noticed  that I can't select any Signing Identity with it saying "No Identities from profile "profileName"". And trying to Archive will just popout the same error as paragraph above.

If I choose "Fix Issue" when the error popup, it resets the Signing Identity to "iOS Developer" and the profile to "Automatic". The archive process runs but when I tried to validate or export an error popup; "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate".

I read somewhere that this is maybe due to multiple certificates in Keychain, but I'm not sure which one to delete:

[image: screenshot of My Certificate]

as you can see, I have a number of certs and some seems to have the same name. The 1st, 2nd, and 4th, is the name of my company (with the same id), while the 3rd and 5th, is my name (with the same id).

Now here's a weirder thing I noticed; in Certificates section of Keychain, I have 2 of the same thing (exactly same name) but their expiry date is different with the one without the key have the same expiry date as the one in the Apple Developer page.

[image]

Any idea what's going on (and how to possibly fix it)? Can it be someone (we do have other developer for other projects) actually removes the distribution certificate that I have and created another one (causing the whole thing to not sync)? If that's the case do I need to ask him to export it and send it to me? Thank you.

Comment: If you are not experienced and at ease with all of this, the simpler is to remove the certificates from your Keychain and the provisionning profiles from Xcode, and recreate them from start with only those you need. This is a lengthy process (count 1 hour for inexperienced developer) but it is harmless for your app. Only the appID/bundleID need to be constant.

Comment: I'm considering that option as a last method, but right now I'm trying to try to fix it by getting the correct certs instead (feel like there's where the problem is). Can I just delete everything in Keychain's My Certificate and xCode's Provisioning Profile? Or is there some that I shouldn't touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:

If you can use the computer that generated the certificate.

Xcode -> preferences -> Choose account -> viewDetails -> choose certificate (Distribution) -> Click setting button and export it

Copy to your computer Do same step but import this time.

Case 2:

IF you don't have the computer that generated the certificate.

You have to revoke the certificate and create a new one. (you have to be admin)

Xcode -> preferences -> Choose account -> viewDetails -> choose certificate (Distribution) -> Click setting button and Revoke it.
And Request new by clicking + button beside the setting. And use it.

OR

You can revoke it form  https://developer.apple.com and regenerate.

Comment: One of those certificates has more information than the other though (see the tree-view expansion on one and not the other?).

Comment: I tried deleting both of them (since the newer one doesn't have key) and downloading the certificate from the web and importing it. But it seems it's importing a certificate without a key and is placed in Certificate instead of My Certificate.  Is this because someone else created it and that person is the only one that have the key?

Comment: This work! I followed the case 2 and revoked it in the Developer site and make a new one instead, and connect the profile to the new cert. Although turns out I need to make the build to be 64-bit support (Apple's rule)... but that's another issue (just need to make a new build). The problem have been solved, thank you very much.